# Extract custom data format in TCP payload using golang

Tags: go, tcp, telnet

I have an industrial sensor which is connected to a [Interface Module](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/manuals/man--IF1032-ETH--en.pdf) that provides information to the end user via `telnet`.

#### Telnet Configuration

Port: 10001

Data Format: Little-Endian

### Data [payload](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/manuals/man--IF1032-ETH--en.pdf)

```
Preamble - 32 bit
Article number - 32 bit
Serial number - 32 bit
Channels - 64 bit
Status - 32 bit
Frame number M / - 16 bit/ 16 bit
bytes per frame
Measuring value counter - 32 bit
Measuring value frame 1 - N * 32 bit
..
..
```

This should be available after the TCP headers (if I understand correctly) i.e. Payload.

I am trying to learn golang with more practical examples and I am thinking in the following direction:

1. Create a TCP server for listening to the sensor's Interface module IP and port number
2. Extract the payload and just print it out as seperate parameters like `preamble`, `article number` etc. as a beginners task

I have gone through some blog-posts about TCP server/client creations but they only address `string` in their payload. How can I extract such a *byte* orientated custom payload as mentioned above?

#### P.S.

I can understand that this can be achieved in python probably via `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` hence some correlation as understanding would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In section 6.2 of your linked pdf document above there is a table listing the data you seem to list in the question

I would convert that table into a struct and then read into it with the encoding/binary module.  See https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#example_Read for a relevant example

"All measuring values are transmitted as Int32, Uint32 or Float depending on the connected sensor" probably easiest to get them as uint32 and then convert them later